# A word for a person who needs assistance?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who needs assistance in a general sense?

This could be in terms of needing help finding something, or needing a small job done, or help understanding something, or getting an opinion on something.

Pretty much just being helped or assisted in general, not necessarily due to an inability to do the task themselves.

Comment: You'd call them a "client" if you really wanted the job.

Comment: If those helped get assistance from an organization, they may be *patrons, patients, customers, recipients, consumers, guests, users, shoppers, purchasers* (or *clients* as @Oldbag offers).

Comment: In the US, the current fashion in retail is to call the customers "guests" - In the quasi-medical business of aiding the challenged or disabled,(who are not children) the term "client" is favored. (I assumed from OP's question, that he was offering services to the elderly - "client" is a respectful way of saying that someone is a recipient of those services.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that person is help-seeker; similar to job seeker, asylum seeker, truth seeker, thrill seeker, information seeker, publicity seeker
 and attention seeker.

Comment: The OP's question does not suggest that the person concerned is *seeking* help, just that they are *in need*. Many such people do not actively *seek* assistance.

Comment: +1 @ WS2 In this case then he/she is help-needing.The OP is asking for a word.

Comment: Except that *help-needing* is not a term I would use, nor expect to hear. I do, though hear people talk about someone *in need of help*.

Comment: assistance seekers :)

Answer (score 4):

Could it be ***a person in need***?; or a ***person in need of help***?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an abstract term, it could be "beneficiary," I suppose. By the way, there is already [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196780/is-there-a-better-word-than-helpee-to-describe-a-person-who-receives-help) on this subject.